# "422 Unprocessable Entity" error when making POST request with both attributes and key using FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a file called `main.py` as follows:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

fake_db = {
    "Foo": {"id": "foo", "title": "Foo", "description": "There goes my hero"},
    "Bar": {"id": "bar", "title": "Bar", "description": "The bartenders"},
}

class Item(BaseModel):
    id: str
    title: str
    description: Optional[str] = None

@app.post("/items/", response_model=Item)
async def create_item(item: Item, key: str):
    fake_db[key] = item
    return item
```

Now, if I run the code for the test, saved in the file `test_main.py`

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app

client = TestClient(app)

def test_create_item():
    response = client.post(
        "/items/",
        {"id": "baz", "title": "A test title", "description": "A test description"},
        "Baz"
    )
    return response.json()

print(test_create_item())
```

I don't get the desired result, that is

```
{"id": "baz", "title": "A test title", "description": "A test description"}
```

What is the mistake?

Comment: I don't believe you can return a model object directly from a view.  You have to wrap it in a JSONResponse.

Comment: But `response.json() == {"id": "baz", "title": "A test title", "description": "A test description"}` doesn't work either. I'm trying to do what is done in the function `test_create_item()` here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/

Comment: That example explicitly returns a dict, which you aren't doing.

Comment: With a `GET` request I can return `response.json()` without problems. However, inserting the object in `fake_db` doesn't work either.

Comment: I mean the view function, not the test function.  `async def create_item()` returns `item`, which may or may not be a dictionary (I don't know enough about typing to know for sure.)  In the linked example, the view function returns an actual dict.

Comment: So what is the correct way to insert an element into `fake_db` from the test file `test_main.py`?

Comment: How do you know it isn't being inserted?

Comment: Because if after inserting I use a `GET` request I can't reach `Baz` (but I can reach `Foo`)

Comment: Why do you expect the `key` parameter to get any value from your request? You're not giving any key - did you mean to assign it from a `Form` value? You should probably extract the key from the `id` of the submitted item, or create a composite request model (i.e. a CreateItem request that has both item and the key on the root level).

Comment: So in any case should I create a single object (which contains all parameters) for each input? For example: `class Input(Basemodel): key: str, item: Item`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by explaining what you are doing wrong.

---

[FastAPI's `TestClient`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/#using-testclient) is just a re-export of [Starlette's `TestClient`](https://www.starlette.io/testclient/) which is a subclass of [requests.Session](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/0.17.1/starlette/testclient.py#L400). The requests library's [`post`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.post) method has the following signature:

```
def post(self, url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
    r"""Sends a POST request. Returns :class:`Response` object.

    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param data: (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like
        object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param json: (optional) json to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    :rtype: requests.Response
    """
```

Your code

```
response = client.post(
    "/items/",
    {"id": "baz", "title": "A test title", "description": "A test description"},
    "Baz",
)
```

is doing multiple things wrong:

1. It is passing in arguments to *both* the `data` *and* the `json` parameter, which is wrong because you can't have 2 different request bodies. You either pass in `data` *or* `json`, *but not both*. The `data` is typically used for form-encoded inputs from HTML forms, while `json` is for raw JSON objects. See the [requests docs on "More complicated POST requests"](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).
2. The requests library will simply drop the `json` argument because:

   > Note, the `json` parameter is ignored if either `data` or `files` is passed.
3. It is passing-in the plain string `"Baz"` to the `json` parameter, which is not a valid JSON object.
4. The `data` parameter expects form-encoded data.

The full error returned by FastAPI in the response is:

```
def test_create_item():
    response = client.post(
        "/items/", {"id": "baz", "title": "A test title", "description": "A test description"}, "Baz"
    )
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.reason)
    return response.json()

# 422 Unprocessable Entity
# {'detail': [{'loc': ['query', 'key'],
#              'msg': 'field required',
#             'type': 'value_error.missing'},
#             {'loc': ['body'],
#              'msg': 'value is not a valid dict',
#             'type': 'type_error.dict'}]}
```

The 1st error says `key` is missing from the query, meaning the route parameter `key` value `"Baz"` was not in the request body and FastAPI tried to look for it from the query parameters (see the FastAPI docs on [Request body + path + query parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/#request-body-path-query-parameters)).

The 2nd error is from point #4 I listed above about `data` not being properly form-encoded (that error does go away when you wrap the dict value in `json.dumps`, but that's not important nor is it part of the solution).

You said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404952/422-unprocessable-entity-error-when-making-post-request-with-both-attributes-a/70411143#comment124454694_70404952) that you were trying to do the same thing as in the [FastAPI Testing Tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing). The difference of that tutorial from your code is that was POSTing all the attributes of the `Item` object in 1 body, and that it was using the `json=` parameter of `.post`.

---

Now on the solutions!

#### Solution #1: Have a separate class for POSTing the item attributes with a key

Here, you'll need 2 classes, one with a `key` attribute that you use for the POST request body (let's call it `NewItem`), and your current one `Item` for the internal DB and for the response model. Your route function will then have just 1 parameter (`new_item`) and you can just get the `key` from that object.

**main.py**

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    id: str
    title: str
    description: Optional[str] = None

class NewItem(Item):
    key: str

@app.post("/items/", response_model=Item)
async def create_item(new_item: NewItem):
    # See Pydantic https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict
    # Also, Pydantic by default will ignore the extra attribute `key` when creating `Item`
    item = Item(**new_item.dict())
    print(item)
    fake_db[new_item.key] = item
    return item
```

For the test `.post` code, use `json=` to pass all the fields in 1 dictionary.

**test_main.py**

```
def test_create_item():
    response = client.post(
        "/items/",
        json={
            "key": "Baz",
            "id": "baz",
            "title": "A test title",
            "description": "A test description",
        },
    )
    print(response.status_code, response.reason)
    return response.json()
```

**Output**

```
id='baz' title='A test title' description='A test description'
200 OK
{'description': 'A test description', 'id': 'baz', 'title': 'A test title'}
```

#### Solution #2: Have 2 body parts, 1 for the item attributes and 1 for the key

You can structure the POSTed body like this instead:

```json
{
    "item": {
        "id": "baz",
        "title": "A test title",
        "description": "A test description",
    },
    "key": "Baz",
},
```

where you have the `Item` attributes in a nested dict and then have a simple `key`-value pair in the same level as `item`. FastAPI can handle this, see the docs on [Singular values in body](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#singular-values-in-body), which fits your example quite nicely:

> For example, extending the previous model, you could decide that you want to have another key `importance` **in the same body**, besides the `item` and `user`.
>
> If you declare it as is, because it is a singular value, FastAPI will assume that it is a `query` parameter.
>
> But you can instruct FastAPI to treat it **as another body `key` using `Body`**

Note the parts I emphasized, about telling FastAPI to look for `key` in the same body. It is important here that the parameter names `item` and `key` match the ones in the request body.

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI

class Item(BaseModel):
    id: str
    title: str
    description: Optional[str] = None

@app.post("/items/", response_model=Item)
async def create_item(item: Item, key: str = Body(...)):
    print(item)
    fake_db[key] = item
    return item
```

Again, for making the `.post` request, use `json=` to pass the entire dictionary.

**test_main.py**

```
def test_create_item():
    response = client.post(
        "/items/",
        json={
            "item": {
                "id": "baz",
                "title": "A test title",
                "description": "A test description",
            },
            "key": "Baz",
        },
    )
    print(response.status_code, response.reason)
    return response.json()
```

**Output**

```
id='baz' title='A test title' description='A test description'
200 OK
{'description': 'A test description', 'id': 'baz', 'title': 'A test title'}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. Very clear and detailed, I really appreciated it. I have two questions. 1) In Solution #2 > `main.py` > `create_item()`, what would the form be if I had another parameter besides `item` and `key`? Is `create_item(item: Item, key: str = Body(...), another_parameter: int = Body(...))` correct? 2) In Solution #2 > `test_main.py` > `test_create_item()`, is it correct that I must necessarily pass the data through `json={...}`? Can't I pass an object of a class defined in `main.py` (for example `Item`, let's assume for simplicity that `key` doesn't exist)?

Comment: @LJG For 1), yes that is correct. See the FastAPI tutorial on multiple body parameters: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#multiple-body-parameters

Comment: @LJG For 2), an object of a class needs to be formatted into either form-encoded data (for `data=`) or as a JSON object (for `json=`). There is no such thing as passing "*an object of a class*" when making POST requests. I suggest reading through the requests docs on making POST requests: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests. Pydantic offers a way to export `BaseModel`'s into a plain dict (https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/) which you can directly pass into `json=`. Using `json=` would be the simplest approach.

Comment: For 1), it is not entirely clear to me how to use `Body(...)` in the general case. For example `create_item(item: Item, key: str = Body(...), another_parameter: int = Body(...))` works, but `create_item(key: str = Body(...), item : Item, another_parameter: int = Body(...))` no. For example, if I wanted to define a function `fun(item1: List[Item1], item2: Item2, id: int, key: str)`, which parameters should be marked as `Body(...)` (`Item1` and `Item2` are two generic classes)? The goal is to pass `json={"item1": [{...}, {...}], "item2": {...}, "id": 1, "key": "abc"}`.